# What is the difference between describe() and it() in spec.js file in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

When writing the test case in spec.js file in protractor then 2 fields are showing describe() and it(). what exactly the use of them and when to use?

// spec.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    ..
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By reading this hopefully you will come to know your answer.

`spec.js` about (how **Jasmine** a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code works)

It has two main functions

> **Suite** `describe` **Your Tests**
>
> A test suite begins with a call to the global Jasmine function
>   describe with two parameters: a string and a function. The string is a
>   name or title for a spec suite - usually what is being tested. The
>   function is a block of code that implements the suite.
>
> **Specs**
>
> Specs are defined by calling the global Jasmine function `it`, which,
>   like `describe` takes a string and a function. The string is the title
>   of the spec and the function is the spec, or test. A spec contains one
>   or more expectations that test the state of the code. An expectation
>   in Jasmine is an assertion that is either true or false. A spec with
>   all true expectations is a passing spec. A spec with one or more false
>   expectations is a failing spec.
>
> ```
> describe("A suite", function() {
>   it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
>      expect(true).toBe(true);
>   });
> });
> ```
>
> **It's Just Functions**
>
> Since `describe` and `it` blocks are functions, they can contain any
>   executable code necessary to implement the test. JavaScript scoping
>   rules apply, so variables declared in a `describe` are available to any
>   `it` block inside the suite.

For more details, you can see [this link](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

Comment: What is a logical difference between the two? So, `describe` tests a part of a component and `it` tests a feature of that referenced by the `describe` component\`s part. Do I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 5):

`it` is an actual test with logic. `describe` is a container for tests which allows you to divide tests into multiple parts. `describe` blocks can wrap tests that act on the same part of an application or have something in common, for example:

```
describe('Menu tests', function() {
    it('should open menu', function() {
    });
    it('should select menu', function() {
    });
    it('should close menu', function() {
    });
});
```

`describe` exposes a couple of functions, such us:

- `beforeAll` - runs before first test.
- `beforeEach` - runs before each test.

And many more.

`it` cannot or at least shouldn't contain `describe` or `it` blocks inside itself, whereas `describe` is supposed to contain `it` blocks as well as helper blocks (e.g. `beforeAll`).

Answer (score 1):

It's BDD interface (Behavior-driven development).

> `describe` is used to describe an action. A top level describe can be used to describe the entire suite with a single word that can be grepped.

```
describe("getUser", function() {
  ...
});
```

> `it` block simply contains assertions on objects defined up the closure scope.

```
it("should have status code 200", function() {
  assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200, "statusCode is not 200")
});
```

Comment: My doubt is clear. thanks for that but I have one more question is that how many it() we can write maximum in describe?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, `describe` is an description of your funcionality and `it` are yours steps and expects for ther funcionality.

Here exemplify better: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing